How to keep history of data for displaying on dashboard based on selected range of date
im building an dashboard and trying to figure out on how to go about storing and displaying historical data.
I read about the audit table being in place to track change. But how do we go about display the data?
Do I query the data we in a range of date from the audit table and the make changes to the a temp master database to display ? But that seems like a long calculation.

No, whenever there is a problem, like when we need to update the current data, it's always good practice to store the historical changes of the data.
Let's say we have a 'users' table, and now we need to update a user's name. We will update the 'users' table, but also capture the change in a different table.
We will create two tables: 'users' and 'user_history'. The 'users' table has insert/update operations, but 'user_history' is always an append-only table.

Operation 1: Create an entry in the 'users' table.
Operation 2: Update user's last name.

Update the 'users' table.
Insert an entry in 'user_history' which describes the changes we have made.



So, when you are going to show the user history, fetch data from the 'user_history' table. The relation between the 'user' and 'user_history' table is 'user_id', which will act as a foreign key.
Think about how the 'user' and 'user_history' tables look like (also store the version number in 'user_history', updated user data, and old user data to find the difference between changes).
Hope this helps!
